# list.count() vs Counter() performance

Tags: python-3.x, count, counter, performance-testing, performancecounter

While trying to find the frequency of a bunch of characters in a string, why does running string.count(character) 4 times for 4 different characters yield faster execution time (using time.time()) than using a collections.Counter(string)?

Background:
Given a sequence of moves represented by a string. Valid moves are R (right), L (left), U (up), and D (down). Return True if the sequence of moves takes me back to the origin. Otherwise, return false.

```
# approach - 1 : iterate 4 times (3.9*10^-6 seconds)
def foo1(moves):
    return moves.count('U') == moves.count('D') and moves.count('L') == moves.count('R')

# approach - 2 iterate once (3.9*10^-5 seconds)
def foo2(moves): 
    from collections import Counter
    d = Counter(moves)
    return d['R'] == d['L'] and d['U'] == d['D']

import time
start = time.time()
moves = "LDRRLRUULRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRL"
foo1(moves)
# foo2(moves)
end = time.time()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (end - start))
```

These results are the opposite of what I had expected. My reasoning is that first approach should take longer because the string is iterated over 4 times whereas in the second approach, we iterate only once. Could it be due to the library call overhead?

Comment: please provide a reproducible example. Note your first "app" doesn't do anything except define a function... what are your actual strings? The second approach will probably *scale* much better, but it may not be actually faster for small strings.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I added some more details. I think you might be right. However, this problem is from leetcode https://leetcode.com/problems/robot-return-to-origin/ and the results I got were (20 ms for approach 1 vs. 90 ms for approach 2, which got me wondering). They usually have edge test cases where the input is very long but I can't tell for sure since I can't see the test cases they run on this.

Comment: Side-note: A minor optimization opportunity, regardless of how you do it, is to return `False` if the input string has an odd length. Since returning to origin must pair every move with an opposite move, odd lengths definitely don't pass.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**`Counter` is faster in theory, but has higher fixed overhead, especially compared to `str.count`, which can scan the underlying C array with direct memory comparisons**, where `list.count` has to do rich comparisons for each element; converting `moves` to a `list` of single characters nearly triples the time for `foo1` in local tests, from 448 ns to 1.3 μs (while `foo2` actually gets a tiny bit faster, dropping from 5.6 μs to 5.48 μs).

Other problems:

1. Importing an already imported module uses the cached import, but **there is a surprising amount of overhead involved in even a cached import** (the loading machinery has a lot of stuff to check to make sure it's okay to do so); in local tests, moving `from collections import Counter` to the top level reduced the runtime of `foo2` by 1.6 μs (5.6 μs with single global import, 7.2 μs with local per-call import). This will vary a *lot* by environment; on another machine (with less stuff installed in both user and system site-packages), the overhead was only 0.75 μs. Regardless, it's a significant, avoidable disadvantage for `foo2`.
2. `Counter` on modern Python uses a C accelerator to speed up counting, but **the accelerator only provides a benefit when the iterable is long enough**. If you use the `list` form of `moves`, but multiply it by 100 to make a longer sequence, the difference drops, relatively speaking (to 106 µs for `foo1` vs. 140 µs for `foo2`)
3. **You're just not counting very many things**; when there are only four things you care about, **paying `O(n)` four times can easily beat paying `O(n)` once if the former case has lower constant multipliers** (which aren't included in big-O notation) than the latter. `Counter` remains `O(n)` for any number of unique things being counted; calling `.count` is `O(n)` per call, but if you need to know the count of every unique thing in the input, for inputs that are mostly unique, individual `.count` calls for each will be asymptotically `O(n²)`.
4. The `.count` approach is short-circuiting in your specific case, so **it isn't even doing `O(n)` work four times, just twice**; the `U` and `D` counts don't match, so it never counts `L` and `R` at all. `Counter` doesn't get meaningfully slower if it can't short-circuit (all the cost is paid in the single counting pass), but your `foo1`, in the same benchmark I used from point #2 (longer input, in `list` form), goes from 106 µs to 185 µs if I just add a single `D` to the end of the (pre-multiplication) `moves` (making the `U` and `D` counts the same, and requiring two more `count` calls); `foo2` only goes up to 143 µs (from 140 µs), presumably because `moves` actually got longer (adding the `D` before multiplying by 100 meant it went from 2900 elements to count to 3000).

Basically, you had some minor implementation weaknesses, but mostly, you happened to choose a use case that gave all the advantage to `.count`, none to `Counter`. If your inputs are always `str`, and you're only `count`ing them a small, fixed number of times, then sure, repeated calls to `count` are generally going to win. But for arbitrary input types (especially iterators, where `count` is impossible, both because it doesn't exist, and because you can only iterate it once), especially larger ones, with more unique things to count, where consistent performance counts (so relying on short-circuiting to reduce the number of `count` calls isn't acceptable), `Counter` will win.

Comment: Superb analysis! Thank you so much! :)