# Creating histogram from list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This question was a part of the the interview process and I couldn't figure it out.

Given a list of integers, create a histogram where the output is a dictionary. The key are the elements in the list and the values are the count of elements in the list.

For example, inputlist: `[2,3,4,2,5,7,3,2,4]` and expected output: `{2:3,3:2,4:2..}`

I know there has to be a loop iterating over the list and then inserting those values in the dictionary. But I messed up on the syntax bad. Would appreciate if somebody could guide me with syntax or pseudocode. HELP!

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-the-frequencies-in-a-list-using-dictionary-in-python/

Comment: Can you do with or without Python lib.?

Answer (score 2):

This would be my solution using dictionary comprehension:

```
inputlist = [2,3,4,2,5,7,3,2,4]
result = {k:inputlist.count(k) for k in set(inputlist)}
```

However I agree that `Counter` from `collections` would probably perform better as the `inputlist` would get bigger (see [list.count() vs Counter() performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57173516/list-count-vs-counter-performance))

Answer (score 1):

For future reference you can't just provide the question, you need to provide a minimum reproducible example.

Here's the answer anyways:

```
output = {}
inputlist = [2,3,4,2,5,7,3,2,4] 
for num in inputlist:
  if num in output:
    output[num] += 1
  else:
    output[num] = 1
print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from collections import Counter

inputlist = [2,3,4,2,5,7,3,2,4]
freq_counter = Counter(inputlist)

print(freq_counter)
```